# Reinstallation of Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, boot, installation

I'm in the process of rebuilding my Windows XP desktop machine. Quick question just to confirm my plan will work out fine:

It has 2 hard drives. I want to wipe the first, reinstall Windows on it, then clean the second hard drive from the fresh install.

So all I have to do is:

1. insert install disc, boot
2. choose partition I am talking about (i.e. first hard drive)
3. format and install on it
4. boot, second hard drive will load - unchanged.

All good, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: rebuild has a specific meaning in both computing and hardware, and it doesn't apply to re-installation of an operating system. Can you please rename your question to "re-installation" instead of rebuild? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All good, should work fine.

However, as you asked for a better way of doing it... I am sure you will do everything fine, but you may as well disconnect the second hard drive temporarily just to make sure you can't make any mistakes or do anything wrong, then simply plug it back in after setup has finished and you are back in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The process is good, just don't expect that the newly installed OS on the first disk will conserve user rights on the second disk.

If all you want to do is reformat the 2nd disk, this is fine. But if you might need to take take ownership of all file on the 2nd disk:
[How to take ownership of a file or a folder in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421)